# Invoke JavaScript function from HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I can't get why this code doesn't work. I tHink that here is some problems with invocation a fuctions....
Please, help to correct mistakes.

Sorry for asking so simple question, but really can't understand why it doesn't work.

```js
 function myFunction() { 
     var count=document.getElementById("picContainer").getElementsByTagName("img").length‌; 
     var temp=document.getElementById("pict_01").src; 
     var i; 
     for(i=1;i<=count;i++) { 
         if(i==count){ document.getElementById("pict_0"+i).src=temp; } document.getElementById("pict_0"+i).src = document.getElementById("pict_0"+(i+1)).src; 
                                  } }

function generateArray() {
  str = "[";
  for(i=0; i<3; ++i) {
    if (i>0) str += ", ";
    str += -Math.random();
  }
  str += "]";
  console.log(str);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="one"> 
        <button onclick="myFunction()"> Change an image order</button>        
        <input type="button"  value="Generate in the console an array of negative numbers"  id="cmdSwitch"   onClick="generateArray();"/>
        
        <h1 style="font-size:14">Header </h1> 
        
        <p style="font-size:10">Text </p>
    
    
    </div>
    
    <div id="picContainer">
        
        <img id="pict_01" src="http://heaversfarm.files.wordpress.com/2013/01/i-love-maths.jpg" />
        <img id="pict_02" src="http://www.uplandsoutreach.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/20maths1.jpg" />
        <img id="pict_03" src="http://www.milldamschool.ik.org/img/d666f5fc-db14-11de-a689-0014220c8f46-5812526.jpg" />
        <img src="http://www.birdsontheblog.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/maths.jpg" />
        
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How do You know, that Your function doesn't get invoked? Check Your console if it reports some errors. Maybe Your function does get invoked, but stops on some error inside.

Comment: It seems that `generateArray()` is working fine. Both the functions are indeed being ran.

Answer (score 0):

It's working great, but you misspelled the word "length" in `myFunction()`.  Good luck!

```js
function myFunction() { 
 var count = document.getElementById("picContainer").getElementsByTagName("img").length
 var temp = document.getElementById("pict_01").src; 
     
  var i; 
     for(i=1;i<=count;i++) { 
         if(i==count){ document.getElementById("pict_0"+i).src=temp; } document.getElementById("pict_0"+i).src = document.getElementById("pict_0"+(i+1)).src; 
                                  } }

function generateArray() {
  str = "[";
  for(i=0; i<3; ++i) {
    if (i>0) str += ", ";
    str += -Math.random();
  }
  str += "]";
  console.log(str);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="one"> 
        <button onclick="myFunction()"> Change an image order</button>        
        <input type="button"  value="Generate in the console an array of negative numbers"  id="cmdSwitch"   onClick="generateArray();"/>
        
        <h1 style="font-size:14">Header </h1> 
        
        <p style="font-size:10">Text </p>
    
    
    </div>
    
    <div id="picContainer">
        
        <img id="pict_01" src="http://heaversfarm.files.wordpress.com/2013/01/i-love-maths.jpg" />
        <img id="pict_02" src="http://www.uplandsoutreach.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/20maths1.jpg" />
        <img id="pict_03" src="http://www.milldamschool.ik.org/img/d666f5fc-db14-11de-a689-0014220c8f46-5812526.jpg" />
        <img src="http://www.birdsontheblog.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/maths.jpg" />
        
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you might find this code to be more maintainable. `myFunction()` reorders the DOM elements, rather than trying to swap out the `src` attributes. `generateArray()` creates a native javascript array, rather than trying to manually create a serialized version.

```js
function myFunction() { 
  var container = document.getElementById("picContainer");
  var imgs = container.getElementsByTagName("img");
  container.appendChild( imgs[0] );
}

// this is just to make console.log() do something on SO
console = {
  "log": function(stuff){
    document.getElementById('debug').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(stuff);
  }
};

function generateArray() {
  var r = [ 0 - Math.random(), -1 - Math.random(), -2 - Math.random() ];  
  console.log(r);
}
```

```css
#picContainer img {
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px dotted gray;
}

#debug {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3em;
  background-color: silver;
}
```

```html
<div id="one"> 
  <button onclick="myFunction()"> Change an image order</button>        
  <input type="button"  value="Generate in the console an array of negative numbers"  id="cmdSwitch"   onclick="generateArray();"/>
</div>
    
<div id="picContainer">        
  <img id="pict_01" src="http://heaversfarm.files.wordpress.com/2013/01/i-love-maths.jpg" />
  <img id="pict_02" src="http://www.uplandsoutreach.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/20maths1.jpg" />
  <img id="pict_03" src="http://www.milldamschool.ik.org/img/d666f5fc-db14-11de-a689-0014220c8f46-5812526.jpg" />
  <img src="http://www.birdsontheblog.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/maths.jpg" />
</div>

<div id="debug">Debug Output</div>
```